# How to do spell check on text area using element-io

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am using **element-ui**, **version 1.43**.

I want to add `spell-check` in `text` area input(if I write something wrong then red line should appear below that text and on right click i can get suggestion).

How to implement it using element-ui.

Comment: Try explaining what you have done. Its a place to guide and not to give code.

Comment: What have you already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am not getting any kick start or library to start working on this..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `el-form` & `el-form-item` to wrap your `el-input type='textarea'` elements, you can utilize the `label` slot to hook into native browser spellcheck functionality.

```
  <el-form>
    ...
    <el-form-item>
      <label slot="label" spellcheck="true">Notes</label>
      <el-input type="textarea"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
    ...
  </el-form>
```